# Partial grouping of query result

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a custom query in my repository that gets me results be accepting zipcodes or citynames as a value.

These values are served to an autocomplete text input.

```
public function findByZipOrCity($cz)
{


    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('z');

    if (substr($cz, 0, 1) == "0") {
        $cz = substr($cz, 1);
        $qb
            ->select('z')
            ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':czRequest'),
                $qb->expr()->like('z.code', ':czRequest')
            ))
            ->andWhere('z.code <= :smaller')
            ->setParameter('czRequest', $cz . '%')
            ->setParameter('smaller', 9999);
    } else {
        $qb
            ->select('z')
            ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':czRequest'),
                $qb->expr()->like('z.code', ':czRequest')
            ))
            ->setParameter('czRequest', $cz . '%');
    }


    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

I work with this ArrayResult() to output JSON that the autosuggest plgin accepts:

```
$zipcodes = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Zip")->findByZipOrCity($zip);

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $codes = array();

    foreach ($zipcodes as $zipcode) {
        $codes[] = array(
            'id' => $zipcode['id'],
            'country' => $zipcode['country'],
            'city' => $zipcode['city'],
            'code' => sprintf('%05d', $zipcode['code']),
        );
    }

    $response->setData($codes);

    return $response;
```

so querying for 'berli' gives the above result, the autosuggest looks like this:
[image: Autosuggest]

This works fine, now I want to alter (any of the) function to have it displayed like this:
[image: Autosuggest Altered]

Which of the functions do I have to change? Can I group the query already (I need one valid zip though) or just do 'something' with the array afterwards?

Any hint highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You can change in array like follow:

```
foreach ($zipcodes as $zipcode) {
        $codes[$zipcode['id']] = array(
            'id' => $zipcode['id'],
            'country' => $zipcode['country'],
            'city' => $zipcode['city'],
            'code' => sprintf('%05d', $zipcode['code']),
        );
    }
```